# MySql UPDATE optimization?

Tags: mysql, database, performance

Let's assume that I have a table with two columns A and B. There is an index on column A but not on column B.
I want to issue several million queries like:

```
UPDATE t1 SET b=b1 WHERE a=a1;
UPDATE t1 SET b=b2 WHERE a=a2;
....
```

There are anywhere from 1 to 100,000 rows corresponding to each unique value of `a`. On average it's around 100.

For each update statement on average 60% of the rows will not be changed because for these rows `b` already has the desired value. For 30% of the updates none of the matching rows will be changed.

Does it make sense to use statements like these?

```
UPDATE t1 SET b=b1 WHERE a=a1 AND b<>b1;
```

Will it speedup the process by eliminating unneeded writebacks to disk or is Mysql 5 smart enough to recognize that nothing is being changed and there is no need to write back to disk?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In either case, MySQL will have to read the row content (whether it is on disk or in a cache/bufferpool). In either case, MySQL will use your index on `a` as a starting point. In either case, MySQL will not update the row if it already has the destination value for `b`.  Consequently, I don't see any way in which MySQL would benefit from having the `b<>b1` clause.

Arguably, depending on the workload and dataset, the query (with `b<>b1` in it) *might* benefit if you change your index on `a` to be a compound index on `a` and `b` (in that order). In this case, it wouldn't have to hit disk (or check the cache/buffer pool) to find which rows **specifically** require updating (i.e. you'd capitalize on the 30% and 60% you mentioned).  Having said that, now your index will require an update for each update on `b`, so there *is* a cost, although I suspect the trade-off might be worth it.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the extra filter. Mysql is smart enough to not update a value if it is the same, but it's better to eliminate this check. You can confirm this by seeing how many rows were "affected" by the query.

Answer (score 0):

I been thinking to combine multiple updates into single update using `CASE`

```
update t1
set b=
  case a
    when a=a1 then b1
    when a=a2 then b2
    when a=a3 then b3 ...
  end;
```

hope this useful, and if it terrible slow, please include explaination